# How to Limit Bandwidth for Multisite?

Tags: multisite

I know this has been discussed all over the net throughout the years, but I can't find a recent article.

Is there any way to limit bandwidth on a per-site basis for multi-site?
I'd like to limit data per site per month, much like a hosting platform does.

Comment: There's an in depth conversation about this on [WPMU Dev](http://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/impossible-to-set-a-bandwith-limit-on-subsites-ok-why-not-limit-the-number-of-daily-visitors) that offers some insights on the difficulties and possible solutions. I'm not sure there's been much more advancement in finding a viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth limiting is sometimes done in an application but it depends on what you're trying to accomplish by the limiting and what protocols and resource types are served.

If you want to keep track of how many bytes have been transferred for each site you serve, and then stop serving a site after it reaches a monthly quota, you are better off doing that in a load balancer or reverse proxy. A comparable WordPress plugin would be overly complex to produce and costly to use due to added inefficiencies.